# Android Button text changes to vertical after clicking button

Tags: android

In my app i have a button that when click loads a new image into an image view. The problem is that while it does this the text on the button changes orientation.

Heres my code for this class

```
package com.michaelpeerman.demotivational_posters;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageGallery extends Activity {
public ImageView i;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.image_gallery);
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
Button download = (Button) findViewById(R.id.download);
download.setOnClickListener(this.buttonhandler);
next.setOnClickListener(this.buttonhandler);
    try {
        int rand = 1 + new Random().nextInt(2368);
        String url = "http://someurl.com/"+rand+".jpg";
          i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());
          i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

View.OnClickListener buttonhandler = new View.OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(View v)
  {

    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.next:
        loadImage();
        break;

    }
  }
};

void loadImage(){


        int rand = 1 + new Random().nextInt(2368);
        String url = "http://someurl.com/"+rand+".jpg";     
    try {

          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());
          i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

The text is fine when the app first loads with the first button. But the text on the buttons change when i click next.

Here is the layout as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/tablelayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/download"
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:text="Download"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:text="Next"/>

    </TableRow>



</TableLayout>
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tablelayout1">
                        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

    </TableRow>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here are pictures of the issue

[image: When app first loads]

[image: After clicking Next]

Comment: Have updated post to include pics

Comment: Can you share the layout as well?

Comment: Ok i added the layout as well

Comment: in your second table layout where you are setting image position you are missing out '+' android:layout_below="@+id/tablelayout1"

Comment: You only use plus when adding a new id. I declared tablelayout1 already so im now telling it to layout below that.

Comment: It is working correctly in that regard. if that was the issue the image would not be below the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with your modification.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dwnld"
                android:text="Download" 
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="30dp"/>
           <Button
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:text="Next"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" 
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="30dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect other than had to change layout_height of the buttons to wrap_content. Thank you so much. Can you explain to me what this changes?

Comment: in any case 30dp is standard size,but its good u solved your problem. I don't know much of it because I am also new to android. Yes but I know That much relative layout should be used at those place where we have lots of thing to place in single layout.

Comment: With 30dp though it cuts part of my text off. When set to wrap_content it ensures the button will be tall enough for the text.